# Particles in an interferometer in a gravitational field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, quantum-interpretations, interferometry, bohmian-mechanics

Let's assume one has a standard interferometer, consisting of an incoming beam which gets splitted in beam I and II and then culminated again. Now the interferometer is placed in a gravitational field, e.g. the one of the earth and one tilts it so that path I is higher above the ground than path II. This leads to a phase shift which can be observed in the interference pattern.
I have three questions:

1. What happens if one uses photons? Is there also a phase shift?
2. Has this experiment ever been done so that there is only one particle (e.g. electrons, neutrons) at a time in the interferometer?
3. And if so, does this experiment really disprove the de-Broglie-Bohm-Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics, as argued in [1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02055211)?

The summary of the argument is along the lines: The de-Broglie-Bohm particle carries the mass which causes the gravitational interaction and it can only go through one path. However the "empty wave" can also go through the other path but it should have no mass and hence should not interact with the gravitational field leading to no observable effect.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the theory (in particular for photons): is the phase shift going back "down" before recombination different from the phase shift going "up" ?  recombination obviously takes place at a single altitude.

Comment: The 5th point in https://www.univie.ac.at/qfp/publications/thesis/gvdzdiss.pdf describes the experimental setup in more detail. But one can also use a non-tilted interferometer and an electromagnetic field. Then the argument applies to the electric charge instead of the mass if one assumes that the dBB-particle alone carries the charge.